# AWK split file on pattern and name new files after string in first line after pattern

Tags: awk

Consider this file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat > example_file.txt <<EOL
sdk,jalxa,9325
m,head1,3
ae,wea,2232
ax1,awq,2321
m,head1,32
dgf,12a,8923
m,head1,11
bsda,awq,902
9as,wea,1732
ax1,awq,2321
EOL
```

I would like to split it on line begining with `m,head1,`. So the result would be:

file_wea.txt:

```
m,head1,3
ae,wea,2232
ax1,awq,2321
```

file_12a.txt:

```
m,head1,32
dgf,12a,8923
```

file_awq.txt:

```
m,head1,11
bsda,awq,902
9as,wea,1732
ax1,awq,2321
```

e.g. the files resulting from the split should be named after the 
entry in the second column (comma separated) of the first row after the split pattern. I'm struggling with this part (how to reference the next line in AWK?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read in the next line in awk using [getline](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html)

Quick'n'dirty illustration (you should really check its return value and act accordingly):

```
awk -F, '
  /^m,head/ {
    tmp = $0; getline; outfile = "file_" $2 ".txt"; print tmp > outfile
  } 
  outfile != "" {
    print > outfile
  }
' example_file.txt
```

giving

```
$ head file_*.txt
==> file_12a.txt <==
m,head1,32
dgf,12a,8923

==> file_awq.txt <==
m,head1,11
bsda,awq,902
9as,wea,1732
ax1,awq,2321

==> file_wea.txt <==
m,head1,3
ae,wea,2232
ax1,awq,2321
```

If the filenames are not unique, you will probably want to append (`>>`) rather than truncate (`>`).

---

If you want to `gzip` the chunks, then rather than creating plain text files and then executing `gzip` via a `system` call, you can print data via standard input to `gzip` as follows - taking care that you are [Closing Input and Output Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html#Close-Files-And-Pipes)

```
awk -F, '
  /^m,head/ {
    close("gzip >" outfile); 
    tmp = $0; getline; outfile = "file_" $2 ".txt.gz"; print tmp | "gzip >" outfile
  } 
  outfile != "" {
    print | "gzip >" outfile
  } 
  END {
    close("gzip >" outfile)
  }
' example_file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Between this, your answer to my Sunday question and your comment below my now deleted previous awk question, you have solved my problem! I will bounty as soon as I can! PS In my case, the file names will be unique (but thank you for thinking of the next person to read this answer).

Comment: One more question, if I wanted to save them as .txt.gz, and also close the connection (each split string is unique but there are millions of them) I would just need to add ```END { close(outfile); system("gzip " outfile) }```  after the last curly bracket, right?

Comment: @user2413 adding it as an `END` rule will only `gzip` the last file - you will also need to add that to the top of the `/^m,head/` rule (so that you close and gzip the *current* `outfile` each time before setting its new value). You will need to check that `outfile` is not the empty string before trying to `gzip` it.

Comment: @user2413 I have added an alternate suggestion for gzipping on-the-fly